# Magento2: Found unrecognizable text in review

Tags: magento2, review

In our Live site there are we found unrecognizable text like below:

[image]

We have already implement google captcha also, Still, we facing this issue.
Can anyone please check.

I have edited my Question. Please check that strange string in the image.

Comment: how many record you found ?

Comment: I think that is cyrillic alphabet, common for Russia

Comment: Also check this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671906/how-do-i-recreate-these-special-characters-when-testing-a-website

Comment: @Rk Rathod, 5 to 10 till today.

Answer (score 0):

Someone used different fonts or language. It is possible that also  not used `utf8`.  I think user copy paste some text or language to your input box. This is why you get like this.